# Modificar valor de campo DetailView Django Python

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando modificar el campo 'active' de mis usuarios de la base de datos.

```
                  {%if item.active == False %}
                  <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary bot"><a class="bl" href="{% url 'activeUser' item.id %}">Activar</a></button>
                  </td>
                  {% endif %}
                  {%if item.active == True %}
                  <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary bot"><a class="bl" href="{% url 'deactiveUser' item.id %}">Desactivar</a></button>
                  </td>
                  {% endif %}
```

Estos son mis dos botones en la template para poder activar / desactivar usuario, se muestran en la tabla según el valor del campo activate.

Bien, según el href del botón entro en la siguiente ruta:

```
    path('activeUser/<int:pk>', login_required(views.UserActiveView.as_view()) , name='activeUser'),
    path('deactiveUser/<int:pk>', login_required(views.UserDeactiveView.as_view()) , name='deactiveUser'),
```

Y esa ruta me lleva a los siguientes métodos en mi view.py:

```
class UserActiveView(DetailView):
    
    model = User
    template_name='nucleo/active.html'
    succes_url = reverse_lazy('nucleo:user_list')
    url_redirect = succes_url
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super (UserActiveView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.active = True
        self.object.save()
        return context
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('userList')

class UserDeactiveView(DetailView):
    
    model = User
    
    template_name='nucleo/active.html'
    succes_url = reverse_lazy('nucleo:user_list')
    url_redirect = succes_url
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super (UserDeactiveView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        obj.active = False
        obj.save()
        return context
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('userList')
```

Cuando pulso en el botón, en la base de datos se me genera el cambio, es decir, me activa o desactiva el usuario, eso lo compruebo cambiando la url desde el navegador, pero realmente no me devuelve la vista ("userList"), ya que me genera un error 405 ... algo de ayuda porfavor!!!!

Comment: Tu código tiene un gran error de seguridad, cualquier usuario con esa url puede activar y desactivar a otros usuarios fácilmente. Al parecer no hay limites pueden desactivar incluso al admin sitio.com/deactiveUser/1

Answer (score 1):

Su código tiene varios errores, de ellos se deriva que no tenga un redireccionamiento adecuado.

1. La vista genérica [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) no es la indicada para realizar cambios en la base de datos, para esto existe la vista [UpdateView](http://UpdateView).
2. No se muestra toda la vista de la plantilla, pero me da la impresión de que no tiene protección contra [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/), lo cual lo lleva a fuertes problemas de seguridad.
3. Las vistas no tienen ningún [Mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) para protección contra usuarios, estaría abriendo su sistema a cambios en la base de datos por parte de cualquier persona.

Del primer punto se deriva su problema, la vista DetailView no contiene la propiedad succes_url ni el método get_success_url(). Hasta donde recuerdo la propiedad url_redirect no existe en las vista genéricas y en Django en general. Le recomiendo seguir en detalle la documentación de las vistas genéricas de Django, el [tutorial de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website) es muy bueno en este apartado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Rigo, me ha ayudado a comprenderlo mejor. Sin duda voy de cabeza a ese tutorial !!! Gracias !!!